# no matching function call in C++, need fresh pair of eyes

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am building a C++ project for fun and I have the following error: No matching function for call to 'loopAction' I have spent about 1.5 hours trying to figure this out and reading through Stack overflow about what could be the issue. I am hoping that an extra set of eyes will help me find the issue.

I have the following prototype in my program:

```
//Global Constants
const int ROWS = 100;
const int COLS = 100;

void loopAction(fstream &, int [][COLS], int, int, int);
```

In the above example, fstream is a file object, int [][] is a 2-d array, and the three last values are variables.

Variables that I have declared:

```
    ifstream File;
    File.open("deskInfo.txt");

    int n, m;
    char theValues[ROWS][COLS];
```

Here is the call to my function:

```
loopAction(File, theValues, ROWS, n, m);
```

And the actual function:

```
void loopAction(fstream &file, int values[][COLS], int rows, int n, int m){
    char row;

    for (int r = 0; r < n; r++){
        for (int c = 0; c < m; c++){
            file >> row;
            values[r][c] = row;
        }
}
```

}

Please let me know if more information is needed. The full error message is:

> Semantic issue, No matching function for call to '`loopAction`' =>
>   Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from '`ifstream`' (aka '`basic_ifstream<char>`') to '`fstream &`' (aka '`basic_fstream<char> &`') for 1st argument

Comment: What is the full compiler error message?

Comment: I'd also be careful with this: `ifstream File;
    File.open("deskInfo.txt");` as capital letters are typically reserved for class names. This can make your code hard to read, as it looks like this is a static function call.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider, not quite. Static functions are called using the scope resolution operator, i.e `File::open`. But I agree that it goes against all the popular naming conventions.

Comment: I posted the full error message above but it could be the char issue! Nope, still have the same issue-I wonder if it has something to do with the fstream object

Comment: @StoryTeller I'm in the wrong language :-)

Comment: @ErikTena, follow the guidelines to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it is written now, it's very hard to grasp your program in full to see what's wrong.

Comment: @ErikTena change your method to accept an `ifstream` instead of `fstream`.

Comment: @Dai-that was it ifstream instead of fstream! Thank you all for the help and I will learn from this! Thank you!

Comment: @dai: Convert your comment to an answer. Furthermore the explanation is simple, ifstream doesn't inherit from fstream. Instead fstream inherits from ifstream and ofstream. Thanks to multiple inheritance is possible and it makes more sense, then the other way:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`theValues` is typed as `char[][]` but the method signature accepts `int[][]`.

A few other tips unrelated to your original question:

- Use templated methods to prevent array-decay, which would help in this situation (see below)
- Prefer `const` to `#define`
- Be consistent in your naming and capitalization conventions: you're using the Title-cased `File` seemingly arbitarily compared to your other pascalCased identiifers.
- Put parameter names in your method declarations

Array decay (how `foo[N]` turns to `foo*`) can be prevented by accepting an array type (with size) as a template argument:

```
template<typename TArray,int length>
void loopAction(fstream& file, TArray& values[length], size_t n, size_t m)
```

This way you don't need to use `ROWS` and `COLS`, you can use `sizeof` correctly.

Comment: I changed the array from int to char but I still have the same error-I could have sworn that would be it!

Answer (score 0):

I think the compiler error message says it all.  The function expects an `fstream`, but you're passing an `ifstream`.  `ifstream` does not derive from `fstream`. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ for some  detail.